# Is this a safe way to access Grails Configuration in static mapping block?

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I am using the ApplicationContext passed in by Grails to the mapping closure in domain objects to get to the configuration information, like so

```
static mapping = { applicationContext ->
    datasources(applicationContext.getBean("grailsApplication").config.dbList)
}
```

where dbList is my own variable in Config.groovy.

Is this the best way to go in Grails 2.0?  Is it safe to assume this will be passed in?  It works, just relies on the undocumented variable, thought I should ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use   grails.util.Holders

```
Holders.config.dbList
```

Comment: Interesting... I thought all static Holders were deprecated for 2.0, but I didn't see this new class.  I already implemented the other, but this gives me a nice fallback if that were to stop working.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day